# Understanding std::inout_ptr and std::out_ptr in C++23

Tags: c++, pointers, c++23

I've being reading the list of library changes proposed for C++23 and I'm quite curious about the [`std::out_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/out_ptr_t/out_ptr) and [`std::inout_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/inout_ptr_t/inout_ptr) (their `_t` siblings). As far as I understand they are some kind of wrapper for smart pointers to be compatible with raw pointers, but I haven't managed to understand them yet. Maybe someone here is familiar with the proposal or may give a less *ISO-like* explanation or examples?

Comment: I guess the best description you will get is from the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1132r8.html) itself.

Comment: purpose is to use them for C-API which take/set owning pointer (`void foo(SomeType**)` whereas we would expect `std::unique_ptr<SomeType> foo()` C++-API).

Comment: Also cppreference already contains some text regarding [`std::out_ptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/out_ptr_t) and [`std::inout_ptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/inout_ptr_t) (the latter is a bit more elaborate and contains an example)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TL;DR** - it is for simpler and more seemless interoperability between C out/inout pointer parameters and smart pointers

##### Longer answer

Let's separate the stuff. `std::out_ptr` and `std::inout_ptr` are functions used to create objects of type `std::out_ptr_t` and `std::inout_ptr_t` respectively. What are those types and functions for? Let's look at an example inspired by [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/inout_ptr_t) (for simplicity I replaced generic argument with good ol' `int`):

```
int foreign_resetter(int**);
auto up = std::make_unique<int>(5);
 
if (int ec = foreign_resetter(std::inout_ptr(up)) {
    return ec;
}
```

As you see `std::inout_ptr_t` created with `std::inout_ptr` is passed to function taking pointer to pointer to the template argument of `std::unique_ptr`. Before adding `std::inout_ptr_t` interoperation with old C in-out pointer parameters was much more cumbersome and error prone. It would look more less like this:

```
int foreign_resetter(int**);
auto up = std::make_unique<int>(5);
 
int* up_raw = up.release();
if (int ec = foreign_resetter(&up_raw)) {
    return ec;
}
up.reset(up_raw);
```

##### Differences `out_ptr` vs `inout_ptr`

From the proposal [P1132](https://wg21.link/P1132):

> inout_ptr's semantics are exactly like out_ptr's, just with the additional requirement that it calls .release() on the smart pointer upon constructing the temporary inout_ptr_t.

This is because the `foreign_resetter` might delete a pointer before setting a new one, calling `.release()` reserves that behavior and can be safer. Use `inout_ptr` if your pointer is already valid and allocated, and `out_ptr` if the smart pointer is empty.

Comment: can you also mention what's the difference between `out_ptr` and `inout_ptr`?

Comment: Your cumbersome version is buggy. You leak the object in case of an error. But that's actually easy to fix. The bigger problem is the `inout_ptr` version - it's actually more error-prone, since C APIs often don't guarantee the output is valid in case of an error. So you could end up with a garbage pointer in that case.

Comment: @user541686 In the example given, `up` can't be dereferenced in case of error, as we've `return`ed away from it's scope

Comment: @Caleth: The unique_ptr destructor runs unconditionally.

Comment: @user541686 So? It's fine to `delete` a null pointer. If you have an api that is *writing* an invalid pointer value then it's not an appropriate api to call like this, and I'd argue it's a bug in the api. Well behaved apis either don't change the pointer, or write a null pointer there.

Comment: @Caleth: call it a buggy API if that makes you feel better, but APIs like that very much do exist, and people need to use them. Just one example: https://linux.die.net/man/3/vasprintf (*"If memory allocation wasn't possible, or some other error occurs, these functions will return `-1`, and the contents of `strp` is undefined."*)

Comment: @user541686 and you still can account for that case, `up.release()` in the error handler. I stand by my assertion that inventing an invalid pointer value out of nowhere is a bad api. From the link you gave, at least some implementations promise a valid pointer value even on error. It's also an api unsuitable for using with `std::unique_ptr` in the first place, because it requires you `free()` the pointer, not `delete` it.

Comment: @Caleth: Nobody said you can't work around it, my entire point was that there was a bug in *this* pattern, which you seemed to have missed. And no, unique_ptr isn't just for delete, you can give it a different deleter for free() or whatever.

Comment: @user541686 In *this* example, it's the default deleter.

Comment: @Caleth: In *this* example, you have no idea what `foreign_resetter` does either. It could very well allocate with `new`.