# Using unique_ptr with an interface requiring pointer-pointer, to an abstract class

Tags: c++

I'm using RocksDB which requires a pointer to a pointer to open:

```
rocksdb::DB* db{nullptr};
const rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, path, &db);
```

As expected, I'd like to use a `unique_ptr`. However, unfortunately if I do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::DB> db;
const rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, fileFullPath, &(db.get()));
```

I get:

```
error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

and if I use a raw pointer and then create a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::DB> _db; // Class member
rocksdb::DB* db;
const rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, fileFullPath, &db));
_db = std::make_unique<rocksdb::DB>(db);
```

I get:

```
 error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘rocksdb::DB’
 { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
```

How can I use `unique_ptr` with this?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `_db.reset(db);`?

Comment: I thought `reset()` is only if it currently holds a valid value, otherwise it's `make_unique`

Comment: `&(db.get())` translates to get the address represented by the `unique_ptr` and then take the address of the address. Not what you want. The error message you get is because the address returned is in a temporary variable and you can't take the address of a temporary. They just aren't around long enough for it to be useful.

Comment: `db.get()` returns a temporary. What about doing `auto ptr = db.get()` and then `const rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, fileFullPath, &ptr);`
?

Comment: When someone wants a pointer to a pointer, it's typically because they're going to update the pointer you provide with a new address. Get the address from `Open` and then put it in the `unique_ptr` **if it is safe to do so**. Who is responsible for freeing the pointer? Are you absolutely sure it is you? What are the rules for releasing the pointer? Use `delete`? Call `free`? Call a close function?

Comment: Related to [understanding-stdinout-ptr-and-stdout-ptr-in-c23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68918312/understanding-stdinout-ptr-and-stdout-ptr-in-c23).

Comment: @user4581301 This page implicitly implies I can delete the pointer when I wish: http://rocksdb.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Good. Eliminates one potential source of problems.

Comment: @user997112 "Why is `reset` different to `make_unique`??" - see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a raw pointer to accept the value from `Open()` is the correct solution, since that is what the function is expecting.

However, the way you are creating the `unique_ptr` afterwards is not correct.

Use this instead:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::DB> _db; // Class member
...
rocksdb::DB* db;
const rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, fileFullPath, &db);
_db = std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::DB>(db);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/tHoFVr)

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::DB> _db; // Class member
...
rocksdb::DB* db;
const rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, fileFullPath, &db);
_db.reset(db);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/w9lAgx)

`std::make_unique()` creates a new object of the specified type, and then wraps the raw pointer inside of a new `std::unique_ptr`.

On the other hand, `unique_ptr::operator=` and `unique_ptr::reset()` merely update an existing `std::unique_ptr` with a new raw pointer (destroying the object pointed by the old raw pointer that is being replaced).

Since `rocksdb::DB` is an abstract type, you can't directly create instances of it, which is why your `std::make_unique()` calls fails to compile. But even if you could create `DB` objects directly, `std::make_unique<rocksdb::DB>(db)` would be passing `db` as a parameter to the `rocksdb::DB` constructor, which is not what you want in this situation anyway.  You just want the `_db` smart pointer to take ownership of the `db` raw pointer.